# How to show that the beta funcction is well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

The Euler Beta function is defined by $$B(x,y):=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt.$$
To show that B is well defined, i do the follwing steps, so please tell me if they are true or not !

> - if $0\leq t\leq 1/2$,
>     then  $(1-t)^{y-1} \leq 2^{1-y}$, for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$, or $\int_0^{1/2}t^{x-1}dt$  converges if $x>0$, therefore $\int_0^{1/2}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ converges if $x>0$.
> - if $1/2 \leq t \leq 1$, then $t^{x-1} \leq 2^{1-x}$ and $\int_{1/2}^1(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\int_0^{1/2}u^{y-1}du \quad (u=1-t)$ converges if $y>0$, which implies $\int_{1/2}^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ converges if $y>0$.
>
>   > Conclusion : By using chasles relation, we have for all $x>0$ and $y>0$, $\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ converges.

Comment: Almost right. Check the sign of the exponent in the bounded factors.. does it matter?

Comment: @AD. I think yes ! because in the first case for example, $0<t<\frac{1}{2}$ so we have two cases : 1. if $y \geq 1$, then : $\frac{1}{2^{y-1}} \leq (1-t)^{y-1} \leq 1.$ 2. if $y\leq 1$ then  $(1-y) \geq 0$ and $1\leq (1-t)^{y-1} \leq 2^{1-y}$, therefore for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $(1-t)^{y-1} \leq 2^{1-y}$ $\quad (1\leq 2^{y-1})$.